# TFS Power Tool for VS 2017 to access TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I am working in Visual Studio 2017 and connecting to Team Foundation Server 2012. 
What version of Visual Studio Team Foundation Server  Power Tools I should use so it will work as VS2017 --> TFS2012
If possible please provide link to download..
Thanks.

Comment: Which feature do you want to use with TFS Power Tools? For VS 2017, there is only process template editor available: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor

Comment: I am looking for this too. I was able to do a "Find in Files" back in the day with Visual Sourcesafe and was happy to find the TFS Administrators Toolkit extension that does this with VS2013/TFS2012 but that extension wasn't updated for VS 2017.

Answer (score 1):

The power tools no longer exist in VS 2017. The stuff like the process template editor is a separate extension. Things like templating were baked into the web now.